# ¿Cómo es posible la llamada a getClass() en este código?

Tags: java, poo

La cuestión es sobre el método *getClass()* de la clase *Object* y su comportamiento como método "estático".

Acorde con la API de Java, el método *getClass()* **no es estático** y su uso tiene por finalidad acceder a la clase del objeto que la llama. Hasta aquí todo bien.

El **conflicto** llega con las siguientes líneas de código:

```
// load and set background image
URL urlBackgroundImg = getClass().getResource("img/board.png");
this.imgBackground = new ImageIcon(urlBackgroundImg).getImage();
```

Estas líneas pertenecen a un código más extenso (del cual es irrelevante su finalidad) y se encuentran al **inicio del constructor**. El código es el siguiente:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChessGui extends JPanel {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3114147670071466558L;
    
    private static final int COLOR_WHITE = 0;
    private static final int COLOR_BLACK = 1;

    private static final int TYPE_ROOK = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_KNIGHT = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_BISHOP = 3;
    private static final int TYPE_QUEEN = 4;
    private static final int TYPE_KING = 5;
    private static final int TYPE_PAWN = 6;

    private static final int BOARD_START_X = 301;
    private static final int BOARD_START_Y = 51;

    private static final int TILE_OFFSET_X = 50;
    private static final int TILE_OFFSET_Y = 50;

    private Image imgBackground;

    // 0 = bottom, size-1 = top
    private List<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();
    
    public ChessGui() {
        // load and set background image
        URL urlBackgroundImg = getClass().getResource("img/board.png");
        this.imgBackground = new ImageIcon(urlBackgroundImg).getImage();
        
        // create and place pieces
        //
        // rook, knight, bishop, queen, king, bishop, knight, and rook
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_ROOK, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 0,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_KNIGHT, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 1,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_BISHOP, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 2,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_KING, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 3,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_QUEEN, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 4,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_BISHOP, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 5,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_KNIGHT, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 6,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_ROOK, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 7,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 7);
        // pawns
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            createAndAddPiece(COLOR_WHITE, TYPE_PAWN, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * i,
                    BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 6);
        }

        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_ROOK, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 0,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_KNIGHT, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 1,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_BISHOP, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 2,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_QUEEN, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 3,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_KING, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 4,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_BISHOP, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 5,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_KNIGHT, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 6,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_ROOK, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * 7,
                BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            createAndAddPiece(COLOR_BLACK, TYPE_PAWN, BOARD_START_X + TILE_OFFSET_X * i,
                    BOARD_START_Y + TILE_OFFSET_Y * 1);
        }
        
        // create application frame and set visible
        //
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setSize(this.imgBackground.getWidth(null), this.imgBackground.getHeight(null));
        
    }
    
    /**
     * create a game piece
     * 
     * @param color color constant
     * @param type type constant
     * @param x x position of upper left corner
     * @param y y position of upper left corner
     */
    private void createAndAddPiece(int color, int type, int x, int y) {
        Image img = this.getImageForPiece(color, type);
        Piece piece = new Piece(img, x, y);
        this.pieces.add(piece);
    }

    /**
     * load image for given color and type. This method translates the color and
     * type information into a filename and loads that particular file.
     * 
     * @param color color constant
     * @param type type constant
     * @return image
     */
    private Image getImageForPiece(int color, int type) {
        String filename = "";

        filename += (color == COLOR_WHITE ? "w" : "b");
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_BISHOP:
                filename += "b";
                break;
            case TYPE_KING:
                filename += "k";
                break;
            case TYPE_KNIGHT:
                filename += "n";
                break;
            case TYPE_PAWN:
                filename += "p";
                break;
            case TYPE_QUEEN:
                filename += "q";
                break;
            case TYPE_ROOK:
                filename += "r";
                break;
        }
        
        filename += ".png";
        URL urlPieceImg = getClass().getResource("img/" + filename);
        return new ImageIcon(urlPieceImg).getImage();
    }
    
}
```

Obsérvese que el método *getClass()* **no necesita un objeto para ser llamado, como si fuera un método estático.**

Ahora bien, veamos el siguiente **código de prueba** que hice para jugar con el método:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Prueba {
    
    public Prueba() {}
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Prueba test1 = new Prueba();
        System.out.println("TEST_1 = "+test1.getClass());
        
        // load and set background image
        Image imgBackground;
        URL urlBackgroundImg = getClass().getResource("/ch01/img/board.png");
        imgBackground = new ImageIcon(urlBackgroundImg).getImage();
        
    }

}
```

La diferencia crucial con el anterior es que esta vez el método *getClass()* es llamado fuera de un constructor para ser llamado dentro de un bloque estático. Salta el **error**: *Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object*, que es lo que cabe esperar de este método acorde con su definición, **lo que confirma que no es estático.**

Así, **¿cómo es posible que *getClass()* sea llamado "estáticamente" en el constructor y luego no sea así en el *main* del código de prueba?**

Y digo "estáticamente" porque un método estático se sirve del nombre de la clase y este ni tan siquiera eso, sino que pone su nombre directamente. Que yo haya visto, solo puedes emplear directamente el nombre del método para llamarlo si este está construido dentro de la misma clase que lo está usando. Por ejemplo, una clase con dos métodos y uno de ellos tiene, dentro de su bloque de código, una llamada al otro.

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8275761/5587982) me parece que aclara todas tus dudas. Para usar el método en un contexto estático puedes hacer lo siguiente: `URL urlBackgroundImg = URL.class.getResource("/ch01/img/board.png");`

Comment: Creo que bien no me he explicado correctamente, bien no he entendido su respuesta. Juraría que usted me está tratando de explicar que un método estático se llama mediante Objeto.método() y por eso su enlace me lleva a una respuesta que explica precisamente esto. Eso lo manejo bien. Mi duda es la siguiente: ¿por qué la llamada a getClass() falla en el programa de prueba pero es válida en el código del artículo? En ambas se considera el método como estático, pero solo uno lo da por bueno. ¿Por qué? O lo mismo no he entendido bien su respuesta, que es posible

Comment: Tiene dos llamadas a `getClass()` en el método mostrado. ¿Cuál es la que falla de las dos? ¿Qué es *el código del artículo*? Mientras más claridad en la pregunta mejor.

Comment: Entendido, voy a editar la pregunta. Deme unos minutos, por favor.

Comment: Espero que la edición resulte eficaz. De no ser así, dígame qué no termina de ver bien y se lo explicaré. Gracias.

Comment: ¿El problema en sí cuál es? Hablas de que el código funciona en una parte y en otra da error ¿? ¿El error no se resuelve usando LaClase.class? ¿O no es una solución al error lo que buscas sino comprender algo en concreto? Por otra parte, aún no has indicado a cual de los dos getClass() que tienes te refieres.

Comment: El problema es conceptual y la pregunta a responder es: ¿cómo es posible que getClass() sea llamado "estáticamente" en el constructor y luego no sea así en el main del código de prueba? La primera parte de la pregunta dice que getClass() es llamado sin necesidad de un objeto que haga la llamada (esto en el código del constructor que pertenece a la parte más grande de código que he escrito). La segunda parte viene a señalar que en la clase llamada Prueba (último bloque de código escrito en la pregunta) me dicen que no es estático el método, lo que confirma que necesita [...]

Comment: [...] lo que confirma que necesita de un objeto para ser llamado. Yo siempre he usado getClass() como un método que se llama desde un objeto. Por ejemplo: objetoBanco.getClass();. Mi problema es entonces que no veo cómo es posible llamar a getClass() en el constructor sin un objeto que haga la llamada. ¿Me entiende ahora?

Comment: El `getClass()` que tú usas en el constructor hace referencia a la clase en sí misma, es como si hicieras `this.getClass()`, ahí `getClass()` no es llamado *estáticamente* como piensas. Puedes verificarlo agregando estas dos líneas de código en el constructor: `System.out.println(this.getClass()); System.out.println(getClass());`

Comment: Otra prueba: Puedes declarar este método NO estático en la clase: `public void getA(){ System.out.println("Soy A"); }` y probar a llamarlo asi desde el constructor: `getA();` no tienes por que poner la instancia de la clase, porque estás dentro de ella. En cambio en el `main` no podrías usarlo.

Comment: Ostras, pues claro. Vaya cosa no haberlo visto antes. Muchas gracias, A.Cedano. Ahora lo veo clarísimo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refiriéndote a este bloque:

```
public ChessGui() {
    // load and set background image
    URL urlBackgroundImg = getClass().getResource("img/board.png");
    this.imgBackground = new ImageIcon(urlBackgroundImg).getImage();
```

Te preguntas lo siguiente:

> ¿cómo es posible que getClass() sea llamado "estáticamente" en el
> constructor y luego no sea así en el main del código de prueba?

Realmente, en ese contexto `getClass()` **NO es llamado estáticamente**. Simplemente es llamado sin poner delante la instancia del objeto porque ahí estás llamando al método `getClass()` de la propia clase, es decir, de `ChessGui`.

Cuando llamas a un método de la propia clase lo haces directamente. Lo mismo ocurre ahí con `getClass()`. Para comprobarlo, simplemente puedes poner esto en el constructor y verás que lo que se imprime es `ChessGui`:

```
System.out.println( getClass() );
```

En cuanto a usar `getClass()` desde un contexto estático, puedes hacerlo mediante lo que se conoce como *Class literal*.

```
NombreDeLaClase.class
```

O bien:

```
NombreDeLaClase.class.getSimpleName()
```